# Таблица рекордов и другие игровые сервисы Google-play.

Tags: android, c++, google-play

Хочу прикрутить к игрушке таблицу рекордов и достижения встроенными средствами Google-play. Игру разрабатываю на C++. Но я как-то запутался во всем этом, а в связи с этим вопрос: Нет ли ни у кого примера внятного туториала на эту тему (желательно на русском, или хоть какой-нибудь) и/или примера реализации подобного (именно на C++, не на Java)? Буду премного благодарен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге я поставил готовую сборку нужных библиотек (SonarCocosHelper),которую очень легко использовать и которая позволяет удобно работать на только с GooglePlayService.

Сайт сборки: http://www.sonarlearning.co.uk/

Инструкция по установке: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nb3246WCq-s

Инструкция по использованию: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ykW_QWq5sqA